# "Unspecified width fixed" + fluid layout

Tags: css, layout, fluid-layout

This should be easy in the year 2012 :P

What I need to do is have 2 divs, side by side. The left one contains a table. The right one contains a google map.

The left div needs to expand as much as it needs to accommodate the width of the table (so it's a "fixed width" column, but the width is not specified by me). It's fixed width because if the browser is resized, the table takes up the same number of pixels. I don't want to have to specify the width, because the table could be any size.

the right div needs to take up the rest of the space.

Anyone know how to do this? I don't even know how to search for this on google. Every "fixed/fluid" layout I see on the net has a *specified width* for the fixed column.

Comment: not possible with css :P with jQuery or Javascript

Comment: wow that sucks :( can't believe the W3C still hasn't figured this one out?

Comment: yeah i saw a similar question a few days back and demand was the same! I asked him I can help with Jquery But he didn't wanted with it!

Comment: I tried this:

  
     #fixed_div
      {
       float: left;
       position: static;
       left: 0;
       top:0;
       height: 100%;
      }
    
     #fluid_div 
      { 
       float: left;
       position: static;
       height: 100%;
       right: 0;
      }
      

but no joy :(

Comment: Looks like I will have to try using Jquery... but it really is a shame that one can't do something so simple in the year 2012!! :P

Answer (score 2):

Try out this:

**HTML Markup**

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="gmap"></div>
    <div class="table"></div>
</div>​
```

**with CSS**

```
#container {
    position: relative;
}
.table, .gmap {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    height: 300px;
}
.table {
    left: 0;
    right: 150px; /* width of gmap */
}
.gmap {
    right: 0;
    width: 150px;
}
```

**or with jQuery**

```
var containerWidth = jQuery('#container').innerWidth();
var tableWidth = jQuery('.table').outerWidth();

jQuery('.gmap').width(containerWidth -tableWidth);
```

​
​
[JSFIDDLE_WITH_CSS](http://jsfiddle.net/nhUDV/) [JSFIDDLE_WITH_JAVASCRIPT](http://jsfiddle.net/gMfX4/)

Comment: I notice that you're setting the width of the gmap, but I want to avoid specifying the width of either the gmap or the table. Basically the browser should know the width of the table, and it should just allocate the rest of the width to the gmap. With your example, the gmap is 150px wide, but my monitor is 1920 pixels wide, and the table is probably around 150px wide. Which means there's a lot of white space.

Comment: make it with javascript. calculate the missing width like this: http://jsfiddle.net/gMfX4/

Comment: Thanks @algorhythm , will try Jquery :) thanks for the jquery examples.

Answer (score 0):

What about CSS:

```
#firstTable{
    display:inline;
    width:auto;
}

#secondTable{
    display:inline;
    width:auto;
}

#myTable{
    width :"100px"
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="firstTable"><table id="myTable"><tr><td>Hello World!</td></tr></table></div>
<div id="secondTable"><div id="myMap"></div></div>
```

Comment: @ATOzTOA, man this isn't the solution! please delete to prevent yourself from more downvotes! I took my downvote back!

Comment: The problem is that the first column will be displayed fine, but the second column won't because the "auto" keyword will minimize the table width. For example, if the second column contains the word "Simon", then the "auto" width will make the column as wide as the word "Simon.

What I want is for the second column to *maximize*, that is.. even if the div contains only "Simon", the div should still expand to fill the rest of the browser window. The "auto" keyword doesn't do it :( ...

Ideally there should be a "auto-max" and "auto-min".. or perhaps "auto-greedy" and "auto-ungreedy", ala regex

Comment: @AspiringAqib Thanks man... I can only vote to delete... Shall I make the answer empty?

Comment: What should max-width be set to? I have a feeling it won't work